# error when I want to display data from an API

Tags: react-native, display

In the screen that I'm trying to put up. I get the ID of a product. The previous screen being a list of products, which come from an API. I get this id thanks to props.data
The console.log ('props', this.props.data) works fine and returns the correct ID to me regardless of the product clicked.
With the ID of this product, I want to find the detailed information of this product (the reference, the family, the price, the stock etc.).
I created this function to call the product detail via my API.

```
initListData = async () => {
    if (parseInt(this.state.productId) > 0) {
      let product_data = await getProduct(this.state.productId);

      console.log('product_data', product_data)

      this.setState({
        displayArray: product_data,
        loadMoreVisible: (product_data.length >= 15 ? true : false),
        currentPage: 2
      });
    }
  };
```

I think the problem is that the displayArray[] is empty so

> let product_data = await getProduct(this.state.productId);

Doesn't work.

And I get this error: Cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component
Can you explain to me what's wrong ?

Full code

```
export default class Information extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      productId: this.props.data,
      displayArray: [],
    }
    console.log('props', this.props.data) // ok, ça fonctionne, on récupère bien l'ID du produit cliqué
  };

  initListData = async () => {
    if (parseInt(this.state.productId) > 0) {
      let product_data = await getProduct(this.state.productId);

      console.log('product_data', product_data)

      this.setState({
        displayArray: product_data,
        loadMoreVisible: (product_data.length >= 15 ? true : false),
        currentPage: 2
      });
    }
  };

  async UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
    this.initListData();
  }

  render() {
    console.log('ça c\'est data = ', this.props.data );
    console.log('ça c\'est les props =', this.props );
    console.log('ça c\'est le state = ', this.state );
    
    return (
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
        {
          this.state.displayArray.map((item, i) => (
            <ListItem bottomDivider>
                <Icon name='flight-takeoff' />
                <ListItem.Content>
                <ListItem.Title style={{color: '#d35400'}}>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400' }}>
                        {i18n.t("information.family")}: {item.family_id}
                </ListItem.Subtitle>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400' }}>
                        {i18n.t("information.reference")}: {item.reference}
                </ListItem.Subtitle>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400' }}>
                        {i18n.t("information.id")}: {item.id}
                </ListItem.Subtitle>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400' }}>
                        {i18n.t("information.cost")}: {item.cost}
                </ListItem.Subtitle>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400' }}>
                        {i18n.t("information.description")}: {item.description}
                </ListItem.Subtitle>
                <ListItem.Subtitle style={{ color: '#F78400' }}>
                        {i18n.t("information.stock")}: {item.stock_status}
                </ListItem.Subtitle>
                </ListItem.Content>
            </ListItem>
          ))
        }
      </ScrollView>
      );
    }
  }
```

getProduct function : [I just have to hide the real url]

```
export async function getProduct(product_id) {
  const abortController = new AbortController();

  let user_id = await retrieveProfileUserId();
  let lang = await retrieveAppLang();
  let access_token = await renewAccessToken();
  let result = {};

  if (parseInt(product_id) > 0 && access_token != '' && parseInt(user_id) > 0) {
    try {
      let response = await fetch(
          API_URL +
          "/products/" + product_id +
          "?user_id=" + user_id +
          "&society_id=" + API_SOCIETYID +
          "&access_token=" + access_token +
          "&lang=" + lang,
        {
          method: "GET",
          signal: abortController.signal,
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            Authorization: "Bearer " + API_SECRETKEY,
            "Cache-Control": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate",
            Pragma: "no-cache",
            Expires: "0"
          }
        }
      )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseData => {
        if (responseData.status == 200 && responseData.data) {
          console.log("getProduct()::success", responseData.data);
          result = responseData.data;
        } else if (
          responseData.status >= 200 && responseData.status <= 404 &&
          responseData.data.error && responseData.data.error.length >= 3
        ) {
          // Handle error
          throw responseData.data.error;
        } else {
          throw "error";
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      //console.log(error);
     abortController.abort();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could you also provide the code of `getProduct`? I have a feeling the issue lies in there

Comment: I just edited my pst. I you can give me any lead, anything, that would be just perfect, thanks for your time

Comment: Two things: why do you set your `this.state.productId` from your props? That's an anti pattern, is there any reason why you don't use `this.props.data` inside your fetch fn? Second thing: try moving your fetching code inside `componentDidMount`, that should remove the warning. If it doesn't, let's continue looking at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing a few things around and it should work.

I also don't like setting state directly inside the fn, so I propose the following change:

```
initListData = async () => {
    if (this.props.data != null) {
      const productData = await getProduct(this.state.productId);

      return productData; // You are missing this, this is vital!
    }
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await this.initListData(); // don't forget await here if you're using async
    if (data.id) {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        displayArray: [...prevState.displayArray, data],
        loadMoreVisible: ..., // I don't know what do you want here, because again, you receive an object from your backend, not an array.
        currentPage: 2
      }));
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thnaks for helping me I'm a little discouraged. This is giving me ' [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: productData.json is not a function. (In 'productData.json()', 'productData.json' is undefined)] '  My page is blank but With console.log I see displayArray is empty, I'm searching this way

Comment: Remove the `.json()` line and log the product data directly before the return of the `initListData`, what does it give you?